# Is it possible to make a script of commands to be run within vim?

Tags: shell, unix, vim, vi

At my work I do not have access to the vim rc file(yet?) so I was wondering if it is possible to make and run a script of vim commands to quickly get my vi workstation up and running.

i.e all of the :set blahblach commands and what not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your own `/home/lilsheep/` directory? If yes, just put all your settings in `~/.vimrc` and your plugins in `~/.vim/`.

If you can't create those file and directory but are able to write somewhere on your machine, you can start vim with your own `vimrc`:

```
$ vim -u /path/to/your/vimrc
```

If you want to load your own plugins from your own `vimruntime/` directory, place this line in the `vimrc` above:

```
set runtimepath+=/path/to/your/vimruntime
```

Be sure to add these two lines to your `vimrc` in order to reset any and all options set by other `vimrc`s and start in `nocompatible` "mode":

```
set all&
set nocompatible
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `:source your-script.vim`, I think?

```
:help source
```

Comment: Besides, if you want to auto execute a script at startup, rename your script as `~/.exrc` or `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean/need, and I do have my own solution, not the best but it works. :)

I know this solution is a more full fledged solution, but I think it's a better solution than to have Vim do everything through VimL and stuff like that. ;)

Basically, what you need is a dotfiles folder, and a dotfiles repo. I'm not gonna teach you how to make a dotfiles repo, you can find [plenty](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/) [of](http://squaremasher.blogspot.mx/2009/12/managing-dotfiles-with-git.html) [entries](http://dotfiles.github.com/) from Google for that.

Next, what you wanna do is have Git on every new machine, that's actually the only requisite for this method. Besides having the software of course. :)

And then, all you gotta do is the following:

```
# I'll be using my own dotfiles directory for these examples

# Clone my dotfiles repo to the "~/dotfiles" directory
$ git clone git@github.com:Greduan/dotfiles.git ~/dotfiles

# Run my bootstrap file
sh ~/dotfiles/bootstrap.sh
```

OK, so that's easy enough, but what does the bootstrap.sh file do? It does a couple of things, mainly runs other scripts which do other things, but it also sets my preferred default shell for example. Here's a quick excerpt of it:

```
kernel=`uname -s`  # Current Kernel name
time=`date +%H:%M` # Output current time
bootstrap=1        # Now scripts know they've been called by bootstrap file

echo "I'm gonna do some stuff for you, OK? I started doing stuff at [$time]..."

if [ $kernel == 'Darwin' ]; then
    # Set some OSX options
    source ./scripts/set_osx_defaults.sh
fi

# Make the necessary symlinks
source ./scripts/make_symlinks.sh

# Install some Homebrew stuff
source ./scripts/brew_installs.sh

# Setup Vim for first use
source ./scripts/setup_vim.sh

# Set the default shell
chsh -s /bin/zsh
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh

# Install all submodules
git submodule update --init

echo "All right! I finished! It's [$time] right now."
```

So you see what it does? All of these scripts do different stuff so that they're not packed up in one single file, creating confusion and stuff. The files I want to direct your attention to are these three files:

```
# Make the necessary symlinks
source ./scripts/make_symlinks.sh

# Install some Homebrew stuff
source ./scripts/brew_installs.sh

# Setup Vim for first use
source ./scripts/setup_vim.sh
```

Let me explain what each one does...

`make_symlinks.sh` does just that, it runs a bunch of `ln -sfn -v` to all my dot files that I care about, in other words it configures all the Unix stuff I use before I even use it! Making it very easy to run that file and be set to go in a new other worldly machine (it also makes backups of old dot files [COMING SOON]).

`brew_installs.sh` is also pretty easy to guess. It runs a bunch of carefully chosen `brew install` commands, or any commands related to Homebrew really, setting up my Unix environment to use tools that I prefer, over others.

`setup_vim.sh` is probably the most interesting to you... It just makes a symlink to a Python thing in order to stop some errors, installs Vundle and installs all of Vundle's bundles.

Here's the URL to my dotfiles repo i case you need more references, or ideas: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles

I hope this answers your question and gives you enough inspiration to come up with your own solution. :)